# Ctrl-C keybinding is having no effect

Tags: key-bindings, cua-mode

I am trying to remap `C-c`, `C-x`, `C-v` (windows editing shortcuts for copy, cut, paste) using these 3 lines of elisp code:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c") 'kill-ring-save)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x") 'kill-region)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-v") 'yank)
```

`kill-region` and `yank` works well whereas the `C-c` binding does not.
Can `C-c` be rebound? I prefer to set the keybindings myself instead of using `cua-mode` so that i can have finer control over it.

Comment: It depends on where and when you evaluate this code. Well actually, the important thing - that the code that is evaluated after the code you quoted does not set key binding to `C-c *`. Try to fully load emacs and then `M-: <return> (global-set-key (kbd "C-c") 'kill-ring-save) <return>`. And then try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have suggested, you'd be wise to avoid overwriting some of the most common keychord prefixes with your own keybindings.

Here's a stylized example of what's going to happen.  Let's say we have a keychord prefix of `C-c a` that allows you to send messages to yourself based on what key comes next:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c aa") (lambda () (interactive) (message "You pressed a")))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c ab") (lambda () (interactive) (message "You pressed b")))
```

Now, when you press `C-c aa`, Emacs politely tells you that "You pressed a", and when you press `C-c ab`, it informs you that "You pressed b".  Such functionality!

However, let's now say you clobber your prefix by assigning it directly to a command:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") (lambda () (interactive) (message "I've clobbered your other bindings!")))
```

Now, you can no longer get to `C-c aa` to have Emacs tell you that "You pressed a", because the new binding short-circuits the whole affair at `C-c a` and tells you that "I've clobbered your other bindings!"

Now, to make matters worse, `C-c` and `C-x` are two of the most common prefixes in Emacs, so if you hijack them, you'll have to rebind a very large chunk of the Emacs defaults.

Out of the box, `C-x` has its own keymaps (in the plural!): [`ctl-x-map`, `ctl-x-4-map`, and `ctl-x-5-map`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Keys.html).  Further, a great many modes bind `C-c ...` to their core commands.  `C-c C-c`, for example, is the conventional way for modes to say "do that main thing I do."

In other words: if you really want common user interface keybindings, just use `cua-mode`.  The "finer control" you can get by hand-binding the keys will turn out to mean a massive rebinding undertaking on your part: yes, it will be finer control, but it's probably not worth your time.

Comment: thanks Dan,,, i think, i can live without windows shortcuts...

Answer (score 2):

If you want more traditional key bindings better activate `cua-mode`. If you want to remap them manually, you will eventually get more problems than benefits, because key bindings like <kbd>C-c</kbd> are in fact prefixes for a lot of other key bindings, and not only built-in ones. So, if you remap these, you will need to *remap a lot of stuff*.

As an advice, don't do it. Learn Emacs way, or use Vi emulation (I'm not familiar with it, but I guess it's the only widely-used alternative). I myself don't use most standard key-bindings and I don't use vi-emulation either. You could end up with situation like this, but first ask yourself if you really want it and why.

Comment: +1. My personal opinion: **As an advice, don't do it. Learn Emacs way.** If you start using `org-mode` a lot, your `C-c` rebinds will come back to bite you.